What is this registry folder?
Was Looking through the registry and saw this:
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\诺⛹⥷耀t
no clue what it is and it just translates from chinese(simplified) to "promise⛹⥷yaot"


My guesses: (1) Corruption maybe. (2) Or a bug in some program has created this. (3) Or it is a consequence of windows registry being a mess . It was a mess in 2010 and it probably is a mess today.

Such names are usually an artifact of some program providing an UTF-8 or 'ANSI' encoded name to a function that expected an UTF-16 encoded one. (Windows has two sets of APIs, e.g. CreateFile() is really CreateFileA vs CreateFileW, the former takes ASCII/ANSI/UTF-8 and the latter UTF-16.)
Yours in particular doesn't seem to decode to anything valid, though (at least not after it's gone through the website), but it is overall very similar to this entire class of problems:

notepad is displaying txt file contents as weird symbols
Chinese letters showing up when replying to email in Outlook
Can anyone explain this weird activity?
probably 100 more threads


I kind of miss anything about the location. Classes root is the location where file association takes place. So it could be as simple as a program registering this name to open a program.
